# nodejs Error: Callback was already called

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, error-handling, try-catch, synchronous

I am still new to nodejs and developing my own asynchronous functions.  According to the stack trace, I am looking at, I am being told that the following code is getting called back twice.  Specifically the catch callback.

Is there a better way to structure this so if more than one of the variables in the try blows up it only calls back once?

As near as I can tell, since all of the buffer reads are done asynchronously if more than one error out they would all call the catch pretty much at the same time causing my error.  At least that is the only thing I can think of that would cause this error, but for the life of me, I can't think of a way around it.

```
function fun1(buffer_1, ushort_Type, cb){
    cb = (typeof cb === 'function' ? cb : function(){} );
    var jsonData = {};

    try{
        var uint_val1 = buffer_1.readUInt32LE(4);
        var string1_val2 = buffer_1.toString('utf8', 12, 45);
        var ubyte_val3 = buffer_1.readUInt8(46);

        jsonData.Type = ushort_Type;
        jsonData.val1 = uint_val1;
        jsonData.val2 = string1_val2;
        jsonData.val3 = ubyte_val3;

        cb(null, jsonData);
    }catch(err){
        cb(err);  //ln 393
    }
}
```

Error Stack trace.

```
FolderWatcher-3 [26/01/2017 17:16:45.898] [ERROR] Error: Callback was already called.
FolderWatcher-3     at C:\nodeCode\FolderWatcher\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:837:36
FolderWatcher-3     at C:\nodeCode\FolderWatcher\parse.js:116:10
FolderWatcher-3     at fun1 (C:\nodeCode\FolderWatcher\parse.js:393:4)
FolderWatcher-3     at C:\nodeCode\FolderWatcher\parse.js:114:8
FolderWatcher-3     at C:\nodeCode\FolderWatcher\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:4637:20
FolderWatcher-3     at replenish (C:\nodeCode\FolderWatcher\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:871:21)
FolderWatcher-3     at C:\nodeCode\FolderWatcher\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:881:15
FolderWatcher-3     at eachLimit (C:\nodeCode\FolderWatcher\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:4662:33)
FolderWatcher-3     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodeCode\FolderWatcher\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:930:20)
FolderWatcher-3     at process (C:\nodeCode\FolderWatcher\parse.js:87:10)
```

Calling Function

```
    //fun1
    // var eventJSON = {};
    if (eventJSON.fun1 === undefined) { eventJSON.fun1 = [];}
    fun1(frameBuffer, ushort_FrameType, function(err, result){  //ln 114
        if(err){
            callback(err);    //ln 116
        }else{
            eventJSON.fun1.push(result);
            callback(null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you positive the reads are asynchronous? I checked the documentation, but there doesn't seem to be a callback argument you can pass to those methods.

Is there anything in the rest of your code that could possibly be calling fun1 more than once?

If the reads in the try statement are asynchronous, it might make sense to try and implement promises. That's all I can think of offhand.

Comment: I am not sure if its async or not.... thats one reason I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on eventJSON? Is that an ajax call from a page? It's hard to tell, but my first instinct would be to figure if fun1 is being called multiple times, as that seems like the simplest explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it figured out....

By moving the `cb(null, jsonData);` to just outside the try catch block so it happens after the catch(err) instead of before, I am not seeing the same error any more.

```
function fun1(buffer_1, ushort_Type, cb){
    cb = (typeof cb === 'function' ? cb : function(){} );
    var jsonData = {};

    try{
        var uint_val1 = buffer_1.readUInt32LE(4);
        var string1_val2 = buffer_1.toString('utf8', 12, 45);
        var ubyte_val3 = buffer_1.readUInt8(46);

        jsonData.Type = ushort_Type;
        jsonData.val1 = uint_val1;
        jsonData.val2 = string1_val2;
        jsonData.val3 = ubyte_val3;
    }catch(err){
        return cb(err);
    }
    cb(null, jsonData);
}
```